# Partition results into groups of five with dummy data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a data in a table like this:

```
date                cd          no        name
------------------------------------------------------------
2023-01-01         123          100      rec1 samp name
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name1
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name2
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name3
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name4
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name5
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name6
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name7
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name 
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name2
```

I want to come up with a SQL statement that will return three record types(top, mid, bot) for every five records. I want to group it/partition it by date, cd and no. I want every group to have five records each, so if it lacks records, I want to add dummy data.

The result I need is like this:

```
date                cd          no        name             REC_TYPE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-01-01         123          100      rec1 samp name      top
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               top
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               top
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               top
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               top
2023-01-01         123          100      rec1 samp name      mid
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               mid
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               mid
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               mid
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               mid
2023-01-01         123          100      rec1 samp name      bot
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               bot
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               bot
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               bot
2023-01-01         123          100      dummy               bot
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name1     top
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name2     top
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name3     top
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name4     top
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name5     top
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name1     mid
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name2     mid
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name3     mid
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name4     mid
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name5     mid
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name1     bot
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name2     bot
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name3     bot
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name4     bot
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name5     bot
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name6     top
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name7     top
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               top
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               top
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               top
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name6     mid
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name7     mid
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               mid
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               mid
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               mid
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name6     bot
2023-01-02         456          200      rec2 samp name7     bot
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               bot
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               bot
2023-01-02         456          200      dummy               bot
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name      top
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name 2    top
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               top
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               top
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               top
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name      mid
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name 2    mid
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               mid
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               mid
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               mid
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name      bot
2023-01-04         789          300      rec3 samp name 2    bot
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               bot
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               bot
2023-01-04         789          300      dummy               bot
```

I tried using the ROW_NUMBER() and UNION and I can partition or group by 5 but I don't know how to add the lacking records or the dummy data.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT  'top' as REC_TYPE ,* FROM  TEST

UNION ALL

SELECT  'mid' as REC_TYPE ,* FROM  TEST

UNION ALL

SELECT  'bot' as REC_TYPE ,* FROM  TEST ) RECORD ORDER BY  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, cd, no,  REC_TYPE ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(no, 'no','') AS INT))-1) / 5 ,date ASC ,cd ASC  ,no ASC  ,REC_TYPE desc ,CAST(REPLACE(no, 'no', '') AS INT)
```

Comment: I edited the post and added the sql query

Comment: how do you identify which rows goes into `top` or `mid` or `bot`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the result I want. I needed to duplicate the groups into three(top, mid, bot). Every group goes into top, mid and bot,

Comment: Edited the sample data and result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it using CTE recursive(Generate Rows)  and Cross join.
First, we get the Rows that is not there
And finally we add the REC_TYPE to it

based on to my comment, a new group will be created every 5 for each group

```
;with _list as (

        select * from (
                select *,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date_, cd, no ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(no, 'no','') AS INT)) as c
                ,(count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date_, cd, no ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(no, 'no','') AS INT))/5)+1 as cc
                ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY date_, cd, no ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(no, 'no','') AS INT)) as rw
                from Testd
        )a where a.rw=1

) 
, cte  (date_, cd, no, name,cc, n,c)  as(

    SELECT date_, cd, no,'dummy' name, cc,c+1 n,c
    FROM _list
    where c<5 *cc
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date_, cd, no,'dummy' name,cc, n+1 as n,c
    FROM cte  
    WHERE n < 5 *cc

), _listREC_TYPE as (
    select 'top' as REC_TYPE union select 'mid' as REC_TYPE union select 'bot' as REC_TYPE
)

select *
from (
        select date_,cd,name, no ,REC_TYPE
        ,(row_number() over(partition by date_, cd,no,REC_TYPE order by (
        case when name='dummy' then 'z' else name end)  )-1)/5 as r
        from (
        select *
        from (
                select date_,cd,name, no from cte
                union all
                select date_,cd,name, no from Testd
                )s
        )d
        cross apply(select * from _listREC_TYPE)f
)f
order by date_, cd,no,r,
case when  REC_TYPE='Top' then 1 
when  REC_TYPE='mid' then 2 
when  REC_TYPE='bot' then 3
else 0 end,(
case when name='dummy' then 'z' else name end)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TIVulSGO)

Comment: Another thing, when  the group of records is more than five... for example I have six records of same date, cd, no, the sql result only returns records for the first five. The last record was not returned.

Comment: I put the registration number in the second section, you can change it.First, in the second section, change the number five to six. If it is not correct Please send your new sample to solve again. After sending, I will check again

Comment: I edited the data and result in the question. Would you please check it again? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand that you didn't want only 5 records to be produced
That is, you want the number of 5 to be based on the highest count

for 6 rows:https://dbfiddle.uk/8k80nbXM

Comment: In this example, a higher count is used. In this example, there are 5, if you add 6, there is no problem, it will show 6.https://dbfiddle.uk/GWUTcA0h

Comment: I checked my code based on your example that my code is worked  please check again. https://dbfiddle.uk/FP1YWJkH

Comment: I checked it but the result that I need is always groups of five tops, five mids and five bots. So if I have 6 or more records of same date, cd and no, it would be group into five. Since there is an excess of 1 record, that 1 record would have 4 dummy data for top, mid and bot. Sorry my explanation is quite bad.

Comment: I edited my code based on  your comment.https://dbfiddle.uk/7bqJMyNK

Comment: I edited my code based on Last  your comment(Edited sorting)

Answer (score 2):

Join numbers (1,2,3,4,5) with record types (top, mid, bot) and distinct (dates, cd, no_) from your table. This generates all required rows. Now left join your numbered data with above rows, use colesce() for dummy names.

```
with 
  num(rn) as (select * from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) x(rn)),
  str(type) as (select * from (values ('top'), ('mid'), ('bot')) x(type)), 
  dat as (select distinct date, cd, no_ from test)
select num.rn, dat.date, dat.cd, dat.no_, coalesce(t.name, 'dummy') name, str.type 
from num cross join str cross join dat
left join (
  select date, cd, no_, name, row_number() over (partition by cd order by name) rn
  from test) t 
  on t.date = dat.date and t.cd = dat.cd and t.no_ = dat.no_ and t.rn = num.rn
order by date, cd, type desc, rn
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OoCmhk1G)

Comment: Another thing, when the group of records is more than five... for example I have six records of same date, cd, no, the sql result only returns records for the first five. The last record was not returned. Edited the data and result.

Comment: You said in original question, that result should be limited to 5 rows. If you want more in some cases you can make full join, or cross apply. And I see that other members already showed you these possibilities. In future questions please add such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to first generate dummy rows using a cross-apply, which are arbitrarily numbered using *row_number()*.

This can be unioned to the table restricting the number of rows based on the count of existing rows.

Finally another cross apply can be used to generate the top/mid/bottom combinations with an accompanying sequence for ordering (if required).

```
with r as (
  select date, cd, no, name
  from t
  union all
  select date, cd, no, name
  from (
    select date, cd, no, 'dummy' name, 
      Row_Number() over(partition by date, cd, no order by (select null)) rn
    from t
    cross apply(values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0))dupe(n)
    )d
  where d.rn <= 5 - (
    select Count(*) from t 
    where d.cd = t.cd and d.no = t.no and d.date = t.date
  )
)
select date, cd, no, name, rec_type
from r
cross apply(values ('top', 1), ('mid', 2), ('bot', 3))tmb(rec_type, seq)
order by date, cd, no, seq, case name when 'dummy' then 1 else 0 end;
```

Demo [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mqqtxc1u)

Comment: Another thing, when the group of records is more than five... for example I have six records of same date, cd, no, the sql result only returns records for the first five. The last record was not returned. Edited the data and result.

Comment: @orin you stated in your question *I want every group to have five records each* so that's exactly what this does. You could try changing the cross-apply in the derived table `d` to an outer-apply perhaps.